# How to disable triangle on Google map?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, model-view-controller

After request of types from google server appear on map some white triangle. How to remove this triangle? Here is my code:

```
function organizeRequest(category, radius) {
        var request = {
            location: LatLng,
            radius: radius,
            types: [category]
        };

        service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
        service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
    }

    function callback(results, status) {
        debugger;
        clearMarkers();
        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                createMarker(results[i]);
            }
        } else if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                callback(results, status);
            },200);
        }
    }

    function createMarker(place) {
        debugger;
        var icon = {
            url: place.icon, //url
            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(30, 30), //scaled size
            origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0), //origin
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0) //anchor
        }

        searchMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: place.geometry.location,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            icon: icon
        });

        locationMarkers.push(searchMarker);

        searchMarker.placeResult = place;

        locationInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            map: map,
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(searchMarker, 'click', showLocationInfoWindow);

    }
```

Comment: replace icon tag var icon = {
            origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0), //origin
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0) //anchor
        }

Answer (score 0):

the source of the triangle is this:

```
    locationInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        map: map,
    });
```

When you set the `map`-property, the infoWindow will be displayed on the map.
You'll only see the triangle at the top left corner because you didn't set `content` & `position`.

Create the infoWindow without passing a map-property:

```
locationInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
```